# What does the Python error 'imput expected at most 1 arguments, got 3' mean?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and was creating a text-based adventure game on my PC yesterday, when I encountered this error, which I can't figure it out. Could someone explain it to me?

```
choice1 = input('''Oh, you. You are finally awake. You have been out cold for the last 10 hours! I am''' ,giant, ''', and I will be your guide in defeating the dark lord Thaldmemau. Well, shall we get to it?
A: Where am I?
B: Ok, we will go!
C: Who are you again?''').lower()

if choice1 == 'a':
     print('You are in a recovery room in the Realm of Power, one of the seven universes of Epta. ')
elif choice1 == 'b':
     print('Ok, let me just give you a brief overview of what we will do and how to fight enemies!')
elif choice1 == 'c':
     print('I am' ,giant, '! I am a giant (but do not worry, I am a friendly giant). I do have some very good abilities, most of which are centred around the magic type of' ,magic, '!')
```

Comment: `input` is a function. it takes one argument. when calling `input(a, b, c)` that's 3 arguments. You may want to either concatenate those strings, or look into string interpolation

Answer (score 0):

In this line, you called the `input` function with three arguments:

```
choice1 = input('''Oh, you. .... I am''', giant, ''', and ''').lower()
```

If you want to place the content of the string variable `giant` into the string the user sees, you can use string concatenation:

```
input('Oh, you. You are finally awake. You have been out cold '
      'for the last 10 hours! I am ' + giant + ', and I will be '
      'your guide in defeating the dark lord Thaldmemau.'
      '''Well, shall we get to it?
A: Where am I?
B: Ok, we will go!
C: Who are you again?)'''
```

Or string formatting:

```
input('''Oh, you. You are finally awake. You have been out cold 
for the last 10 hours! I am {giant}, and I will be your guide in
defeating the dark lord Thaldmemau.  Well, shall we get to it?
A: Where am I?
B: Ok, we will go!
C: Who are you again?)'''.format(giant=giant))
```

Comment: that's the print function, and it's called with 5 arguments (which is fine)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that's basically equivalent to yours:

```
name = "Tom"
user_input = input("My name is", name, "- what's yours?")
```

Output:

```
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

If I would use `print` instead, everything would work the way you expect it to:

```
name = "Tom"
print("My name is", name, "- what's yours?")
```

Output:

```
My name is Tom - what's yours?
```

I'm guessing that's where the confusion comes from. `print` accepts as many arguments as you want - I'm giving it three separate strings - first `"My name is"`, then the variable `name` (which is also a string), and finally the third string `"- what's yours?"`.

`input` is different. It accepts either 0 or 1 arguments exactly. If you try to give it more than 1, it will raise a `TypeError`.

So, you'll want to use string formatting to solve this particular problem. The idea is that you will generate a single string and pass that as an argument to the `input` function:

```
name = "Tom"
user_input = input(f"My name is {name} - what's yours?")
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` lets you provide multiple `str` arguments, and it will print each of them separated by a space (or whatever string is specified by the `sep` argument).

`input`, however, requires a *single* `str` argument; it is your responsibility to join multiple strings yourself. For example,

```
choice1 = input(f'''Oh, you. You are finally awake. You have been out cold for the last 10 hours! I am {giant}, and I will be your guide in defeating the dark lord Thaldmemau. Well, shall we get to it?
A: Where am I?
B: Ok, we will go!
C: Who are you again?''').lower()
```

Answer (score -1):

The input function can only take one argument. Your input statement with the commas is set up as the first part of the sentence, 'giant' and the rest of the sentence as 3 arguments.
You can use concatenation to fix this, if 'giant' is a string use + to concatenate.

Comment: English as a second language is welcome here but a certain minimum level of English proficiency is probably necessary before questions can be helpfully answered. (Keep studying!)